# Bind List of strings to UI as Checkboxes?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a `List<String>` in a custom user control. Whenever the `List<String>` is modified, I want the custom user control to have checkboxes for every item in the `List<String>`. My original idea (being used to Java) was to just add the checkboxes and remove them directly.

But... I know C# can do better than that. Is there some way I can "bind" the strings to the UI so they show up as checkboxes? (or any other method that works?)

Comment: (My XAML is a bit rusty, so I'll just leave the idea here so someone can pick it up and write a complete answer, or that you get the idea.) You can use a `ItemsControl` with an item template that is a checkbox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that easily by binding an `ItemsControl` to the list of strings:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

However that's not very useful, because you have no easy way to access the state of the `CheckBox`... A better option would be to wrap the string in a class that also exposes a `bool` property:

```
public class CheckableItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CheckableItem(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You can then expose a list of `CheckableItem<string>` instead of a list of strings, and change the XAML as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Value}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you need to test if the `CheckBox` is checked, just test the `IsChecked` property in the `CheckableItem<T>` class.

If you need the `CheckBox` to have 3 states (checked/unchecked/indeterminate), just declare IsChecked as `bool?` instead of `bool`.

Comment: Could you give more information on how to do the wrapping? At this moment I use a foreach loop to go over each item. But How Do I use your CheckableItem class to convert my current list to a list of checkable items? Does my question make sense to you? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.jarloo.com/how-to-create-a-checkedlistbox-in-wpf/

@Thomas Levesque No longer needed, this link explains it all in detail, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.